# wikitude image overlay Uncaught ReferenceError: AR is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, wikitude

Im learning to use Wikitude and tryout few AR scenarios. I could load the sample code on Android API 22 phone using Android Studio.Later I tried the Image overlay part of sample code as a separate package under same project. Camera is launched on a button press with wikitude trail marks, but the image overlay doesn't work. I notice this error which is different from the working sample logs:

```
07-10 01:58:31.585    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples I/Android Callback﹕ ARchitect Build: 9ad0da2
07-10 01:58:31.645    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples E/AugmentedActivity﹕ Loaded the asset folder/web app correctly
07-10 01:58:31.665    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: 0, ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor, 20000, 0,
07-10 01:58:31.675    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: 1, AK09911C Magnetic field Sensor, 20000, 0,
07-10 01:58:31.685    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: 0, ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor, 20000, 0,
07-10 01:58:31.695    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples D/NetworkStateReceiver﹕ Network connectivity change
07-10 01:58:31.795    7109-8287/com.wikitude.sdksamples E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
07-10 01:58:32.145    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 7109
07-10 01:58:32.215    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: AR is not defined", source:  (1)
07-10 01:58:32.215    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@11fcbe2f time:105224168
07-10 01:58:32.395    7109-8401/com.wikitude.sdksamples E/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [unnamed-7109-0] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=5 undequeued=1)
07-10 01:58:32.505    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples V/ActivityThread﹕ updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{3b03ef9d token=android.os.BinderProxy@180381fe {com.wikitude.sdksamples/com.wikitude.virtualhome.MainActivity}} show : false
07-10 01:58:48.735    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener ::
07-10 01:58:48.815    7109-8524/com.wikitude.sdksamples D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener ::
07-10 01:58:48.825    7109-8524/com.wikitude.sdksamples D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener ::
07-10 01:58:49.205    7109-7109/com.wikitude.sdksamples V/ActivityThread﹕ updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{365c8517 token=android.os.BinderProxy@11fcbe2f {com.wikitude.sdksamples/com.wikitude.virtualhome.AugmentedActivity}} show : true
```

Does this mean, AR object from architect.js is not getting created?

Comment: Please put the log output into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. My mistake!

Changed code:                `this.architectView.load(getAssets().open("arviews/ImageOnTarget/index.html").toString());`

to

```
this.architectView.load("arviews/ImageOnTarget/index.html");
```